# Converting imperial to metric in excel with text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data in cell A1:

```
diam 4.5" x 7.88"
0.83 lbs (note that there is a line break within the cell)
```

and would like to create a formula to convert the data from A1 to cell B2 to produce:

```
diam 12cm x 18cm
.38 kg
```

length would always be rounded up to the nearest cm and weight would also be rounded up to the nearest hundredth kg

Also would like to perform a similar formula for converting below:

```
4.5" x 7.88" x 20"
.83 lbs
```

to

```
12cm x 20cm x 51cm
.38 kg
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complicated answer -

```
="diam "&ROUND(MID(A1, 5, FIND("""",A1, 1)-6)*2.54, 0) & "cm x "& ROUND(MID(A1, FIND("x", A1)+2, FIND("""",A1, FIND("""",A1, 1)+1)-FIND("x", A1)-2)*2.54, ) &"cm"&CHAR(10)&ROUND(MID(A1, FIND("""",A1, FIND("""",A1, 1)+1)+2, FIND("lbs", A1)- FIND("""",A1, FIND("""",A1, 1)+1)-3) * 0.453592, 2)& "kg"
```

Simpler will be if you break your string in 3 columns (assuming, you have multiple such string in Column A), and then do the calculation and then join back.

Comment: I'm getting errors trying this formula. Unfortunately, this column is very long and formatted for printing so I would prefer to not break into multiple columns.

Comment: I see the question edited. I have edited the answer too, this will give you line break, please make sure that you have wrap text on in the result cells

Comment: Works great! How might I do the same for 27" x 14" x 18"
23 lbs (line break at 23 lbs)

Comment: @Platypus17 - Spreadsheets should be broken down into input, calculations, and reports - and data should flow in that order. You seem to be trying to reverse the flow.